# When is the gluing of two finite type affine Z-schemes affine?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $A$ and $B$ be finitely generated $\mathbf{Z}$-algebra. Suppose that there exists two coprime integers $m$ and $n$ and an isomorphism of $\mathbf{Z}$-algebra
$\phi:A\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}}\mathbf{Z}[1/n]\simeq B\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}}\mathbf{Z}[1/m] $. Then we can glue $A$ and $B$ along $\phi$ so that we obtain
a scheme $Y$ over $Spec(\mathbf{Z})$.

**Q1**: Under what general conditions do we have $Y$ affine ?

**Q2**: In the case where $Y=Spec(C)$ is affine then how do we construct the $\mathbf{Z}$-algebra $C$ from the triple $(A,B,\phi)$?

Comment: You probably mean "an iso. of algebras $A\otimes_{\bf Z}{\bf Z}[1/(nm)]\simeq B\otimes_{\bf Z}{\bf Z}[1/(nm)]$". If that is the case, then the morphism $Y\to {\rm Spec}\ {\bf Z}$ is affine (see ex. 5.17, p. 128 in Hartshorne). You can then use Ex. 4.1, p. 222 in Hartshorne and Serre's criterion for affineness to conclude that $Y$ is affine.

Comment: A toy example I had in mind was $Z[1/2][1/3]\simeq Z[1/3][1/2]$ where $n=3$ and $m=2$. If we glue them along the isomorphism then we get $Z$. Anyhow thanks a lot for the reference, I'll look at it

Comment: So I think that proof you were suggesting is correct. So it seems to me that there should be an (obvious) direct construction of $C$ but I don't see it...

Comment: By Zariski glueing on affine schemes,$$C=\{(a,b)\in A\times B\mid \phi(a\otimes1)=b\otimes1\}.$$

Comment: Beautiful! I never internalized fibered products in the category of rings but now with this example I see their importance! Please Laurent, copy and paste your equality so that I can checkmark your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Zariski glueing on affine schemes,
$$C=\{(a,b)\in A×B\mid\phi(a\otimes1)=b\otimes1\}.$$
Of course the beautiful thing in this story is the answer to Q1: if $f:Y\to X$ is an affine morphism and $X$ is an affine scheme, then $Y$ is affine. Once you know this, the only possible answer to Q2 is the above.